# Array to string conversion - Form Model Binding in Blade Templating Engine

Tags: php, laravel, layout, yield, laravel-blade

Trying to update the fields using Form Model Binding, but I am stuck as the following error got displayed:

> ErrorException in HtmlBuilder.php line 431: Array to string conversion
>   (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\resources\views\posts\edit.blade.php)

**Edit.blade.php**

```
{!! Form::model($post, ['method'=>'PUT', ['action'=>'PostsController@update', $post->id]]) !!}

        {{ csrf_field() }}
        {!! Form::label('title', 'Title: ') !!}
        {!! Form::text('title', null) !!}
        {!! Form::submit('Update Post') !!}

    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

**Htmlbuilder.php [Line 430-432]**

```
if (! is_null($value)) {
            return $key . '="' . e($value) . '"';
        }
```

I have tried numerous solutions but got no success. I don't know where the problem is.

Comment: Could you please specify which line is line 431?

Comment: I have total of 24 lines in Edit.blade.php @PatrickMlr

Comment: line 431 in HtmlBuilder.php ? And the calling part in edit.blade.php -  paste it and update the question

Comment: Please add the code from HtmlBuilder.php - line 431 to your description. It would help if you tell us where you set the var and whats in it.

Comment: is $post an array or an object?

Comment: $post in an object @TalhaMalik

Answer (score 2):

Try this code where you send options as associative array: `['method' => value, 'action' => value]` but not a mix `['method' => value, ['action' => value]]`

```
{!! Form::model($post, ['method'=>'POST', 'action'=>['PostsController@update', $post->id]]) !!}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing some brackets. The value of `action` should be an array.

Try the following **(write in a single line)**:

```
{!! Form::model($post,
    ['method'=>'PUT', 'action'=>
        [ 'PostsController@update', $post->id]
    ])
!!}
```